# Requesting user input using JOptionPane

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program which will ask for a number above 10, and then display a relevant dialog box. Here's what I have so far, and I don't really know if I'm on the right track.

```
int userInput;

if ( userInput < 10)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Thank you.", "Confirmation",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Your number is not big enough", "Confirmation",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

How can I make Java ask for input?

Comment: Look at [`JOptionPane.showInputDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [`JOptionPane.showInputDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29):

See [Getting the User's Input from a Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) in the [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) Tutorial:

```
String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a number.");
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks right from what I've been trying. The problem is now that it has a problem with 'void'. What does it need to be instead of void, in order to be able to receive input? - exact message, 'cannot convert from void to String'

Comment: It was a typo - I typed `showMessageDialog` instead of `showInputDialog`. Try now (and also try to understand what is being done :-) )

Comment: Thanks to the tutorial, I've got it. Thanks.